# How to call setInterval from Asp.Net button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, timer, setinterval

How can I call setInterval from Asp.Net button?
I need to start a timer from Asp.Net button then want to use a code behind method for it.

I call StartTimer function from the button but setInterval not starts :

**Aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Timer</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function StartTimer() {    
        var count = 30;

        var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); // 1000 will  run it every 1 second
    }
    function timer() {
        count = count - 1;

        if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        //counter ended
        return;
        }

        var today = new Date();
        var second = today.getSeconds();

        alert(second);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonStart" runat="server" Text="Start timer" OnClientClick="return StartTimer();" OnClick="ButtonStart_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some code
}
```

**Update**

Messagebox never pops up.

It seems I could not call a Javascript function from another function.

---

**Fixed code belonging to Koby Douek's answer** :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>jQuery Timer</title>
<script src="../jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count;

    function StartTimer() {
        count = 30;

        var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); // 1000 will  run it every 1 second
    }
    function timer() {
        count = count - 1;

        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            //counter ended
            return;
        }

        var today = new Date();
        var second = today.getSeconds();

        alert(second);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonStart" runat="server" Text="Start timer" OnClick="ButtonStart_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

protected void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "StartTimer();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegisterStartupScript` to register a script on postback:

```
protected void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "StartTimer();", true);
}
```

You will need to remove: `OnClientClick="return StartTimer();"` from the Button properties.

Also - In your `<script>`:

Change: `var count = 30`;
to: `count = 30;`

and add:
`var count;`

below: `<script type="text/javascript">`

This way your `count` variable will be scoped correctly.

For further reading: [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

**A more elegant solution ?**

Change the `<asp:Button>` to a simple `<input>`, and remove all server code:

```
<input type="button" id="ButtonStart" value="Start timer" onclick="StartTimer();" />
```

Comment: So you say to run the jquery method from code behind rather than from aspx, okey I'm going to try.

Comment: Also, please read my update for a more elegant solution, if you don't really need the postback...

Comment: I need to run with the Asp.net button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137931/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-mrbengi).